# Regex match for anything EXCEPT pattern

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I am coding in Java here.

I know that the regex for matching any number or string of letter is

```
"(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\\.[0-9]+)?|[a-zA-Z]+"
```

But I would like to match anything except letter or number, ie symbols like `!, @, +, -`

I tried doing `[^.. ]` but it doesn't work.

For example, let's say I want to do the opposite, ie return all parts of the string that contains numbers or strings of letters or @, I would do

```
public ArrayList<String> findMatch(String string){
    ArrayList <String> outputArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\\.[0-9]+)?|[a-zA-Z]+|\\@");
    // recognizes number, string, and @
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string)
    while (m.find()) {
        outputArr.add(m.group());
    }
    return outputArr;
}
```

Let's say I want to find the opposite of the code above, how can I change line 3?

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to use just this:

```
\W+
```

That will match a string of any characters that aren't "word characters", defined as:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

or "all letters, numbers, and underscore". If you want to include underscore, try the following:

```
[\W_]+
```

Or, if you'd rather have it explicit:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Which means "everything but letters and numbers".

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ Sean Johnson I don't want to match strings like "02323", that's why I had 0|[1-9][0-9]*

I also don't want to match strings like "2." or ".". But "2.3" will be accepted.

Comment: @user2163834: So just floating point numbers basically, or is there more to it?

Comment: I don't want any floating point numbers or strings of letters. I want to return everything else.

Comment: @user2163834 "I would like to match anything except letter or number" doesn't agree with "But 2.3 will be accepted".  Please try to clarify what you are trying to capture; a couple of example strings would help

Comment: @lxop, yes I meant I know for a fact that (0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\\.[0-9]+)?|[a-zA-Z]+ accepts opposite of what I want, but [a-zA-Z0-9_] also accepts 0132321 as well as 2.3

Comment: recognizes "@#@#@!(" in "@#@#@!(", recognizes "!@!" and "#" in "!@!1#11", recognizes nothing in "2.33333xyz", recognizes "." in "x.y"

Answer (score 1):

The simplest regex pattern that you can use is : [^\w]+
This will match all the special characters which are neither numbers nor alphabets. Hope this helps. This is a sample [Regex Tester](http://www.regextester.com/) with sample examples. You can test your regex for correctness over here. Hope this will help you.

From the example you have provided what I understand is, you want all the characters except alphabets, numbers and '@'.

In regex **'\w'** matches any alphabet(including underscore) and any number. So you need to negate this, to get other symbolic characters like '$,#' etc.

Below expression will solve your issue = **[^\w@]+**

**'^'** indicate negation symbol. Here **'^\w'** meaning 'match anything except alphabets or numbers'. I have also added **'@'** symbol in the expression as you need to ignore it as well.

Hope this will answer your question.

Comment: @ Ankur, I am looking to do it in the negation format, because the next few parts are also like that...

Comment: Can you please explain this with a sample example, it will help me understand exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you can give some more detail, what is your requirement? and what you expect?
It will help me to figure out the solution.
What you put in your query looks like you want to match special characters only. Am I right?
If so you can just try:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9][your quantifier here]  
quantifier can be:
? for 0 or 1 frequency
+ for >=1 frequency
* for >=0 frequency
```

Suppose you have a String like

```
String s="shyuit6785%^7kui!@*&123f#$annds";

//And you want to find out the characters except alphabets and numerals . (I hope its your requirement)
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9@]+");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
 while (m.find())
  {
   System.out.println("Found a required character " + m.group() + " at index number " +m.start());

  }
```

Comment: I want to find the parts of the string that is *NOT* numbers (ie 12, 12.22), or string of letters (AbacD, Idontknowthis).

Comment: The second part of the problem is find parts of the string that strings that is NOT strings of letters, as defined above, or "@", or ".com"

Comment: ok I am just editing my answer and adding something, hope it will help you to get your solution.